# Secure file upload via Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

What are the suggested tips and tricks you have implemented in Grails to ensure the file uploaded via `<input type="file" ....>` in a publicly available websites are least harmful? I am thinking about using contenttype to ensure only the Word or PDF files are allowed to upload. But I am not sure how we can prevent the Word or PDF files with executable information to be uploaded? Is there any additional filtering we can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g.:

```
<input type="file" maxlength="5242880" accept="application/pdf"/>
```

Inside the upload action you can use ([ClamAV](https://grails.org/plugin/clamav))to scan for viruses.

But this leads a further problem. If the uploaders renames any file to ".pdf" it can be uploaded too. Also contentType returns "application/pdf" even if the file isn't really one.

Solution:
You must read the first line of the document and check if it begins with "%PDF". If you open your PDF e.g. with Sublime Text Editor you can see it.